# $f(x)=cx+\dfrac{1}{x^2+3}$. Find the values of c for which f(x) is increasing for all $x$

Tags: calculus, inequality

$f(x)=cx+\dfrac{1}{x^2+3}$. Find the values of c for which f(x) is increasing for all $x$

I found $$f'(x) =c-\dfrac{2x}{\left( x^2+3\right)^2}$$

But I am having a tough time moving from here.

I know we have to find $c$ for which the following Inequality is satisfied for all $x$

$$c-\dfrac{2x}{\left( x^2+3\right)^2}>0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  You need
$$c-\dfrac{2x}{\left( x^2+3\right)^2}\ge0$$
for all $x$, that is, $c$ is greater than or equal to the maximum value of $2x/(x^2+3)^2$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: i do know that, but how do we find the maximum value of $2x/(x^2+3)^2$

Comment: Have you studied differentiation and how to use it for maximum problems?

Comment: yes i have, but this one looks very complicated

Comment: If you show all your work and explain where you got stuck somebody may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum, here is one way.  First, we need to worry only of positive $x$. Then:
$$ \dfrac{2x}{(x^2+1+1+1)^2} \le \frac{2x}{(4\sqrt{x})^2}=\frac18$$
where we have used AM-GM, and equality is obtained when $x=1$.

---

P.S. Also note you can have $c = \frac18$ as the question does not insist on the function being strictly increasing.